# Segmented Keys in ACUMATICA

Tags: acumatica

I’ve created new [Segmented Keys in ACUMATICA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NguQB.jpg) for use in a specific module. I would like to assign the Dimension name dynamically but I noticed it works only with hard code or name like [PXDimension(“VENDOR”)]

Also, I have some limitation to create an IF Conditional inside the customized field… it does not recognize the IF clause (see the image).
I would appreciate any suggestion how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen how your original attempt at `PXDimension` looked, but I'm going to take a guess and assume you tried to reference a new custom field contained in a setup table, something like:

```
[PXDimension(typeof(XXMySetup.usrMyCustomField))]
```

If that's indeed what you tried to do, one very important thing to do is to ensure that you have a view for your table in your graph, otherwise the attribute will not find the table and record in your cache. For instance:

```
public PXSetup<XXMySetup> XXMySetup;
```

Without this view declared in the graph, the dimension attribute will not work as expected. It would be nice if a clear exception was thrown in this case - I made the same mistake recently and it would have been helpful.

Comment: Gabriel, I appreciate so much your response to my question. 
What I understand is that PXDIMENSION can work dynamically with the new custom field values. I’ve tried to apply the attribute you suggest but it doesn’t recognize the view of my custom table even though I’ve declared in the graph. Is it possible to share with me any code or script you did? The version of Acumatica is 6.1. 
Thank you very much. 

Pedro

Comment: Without a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example it will be difficult to provide more guidance - the only thing we have is a screenshot you shared which shows an unusual mix of DAC attributes and executable code https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve